# Get the symbol contain names

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am new for word macros. Can you anyone please suggest to me how to write a code in macros for the below solution.

I need to get the text contains special symbols("-") in between text in the word document macros.

This is the heading we are using in word, Each heading having serial number also

```
1 test1
2 test2
3 -  test3 -  
4 test4
5 -  test5 -  
6 test6
7 -  test7 -  
8 test8
9 -  test9 -  
10 test10
11 test11
12 -  test12 -  
13 test13
14 -  test14 -
```

the result should be like

```
3 -  test3 -  
5 -  test5 -  
7 -  test7 -  
9 -  test9 -  
12 -  test12 -  
14 -  test14 -
```

This is the sample code I wrote but it not working it getting only single text "-" in the collection

```
Public Function GetVariablesFirstLevel() As Collection
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim objVar As variable
    Dim colAux As Collection
    Dim strAux As String
    Dim objStoryRange As Range
    Dim forceExitLoop As Boolean
            
    Set colAux = New Collection
    For Each objStoryRange In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        objStoryRange.Select
        Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart
        With Selection
            With .Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = "-"
                .Replacement.Text = ""
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindStop
                .Format = False
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchWildcards = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
            End With
            forceExitLoop = False
            Do While (.Find.Execute And Not forceExitLoop)
                strAux = Trim$(Replace$(Right(.Text, 1), vbCr, vbNullString))
                If (strAux <> vbNullString) Then
                    If (Not IsReplacementOfAVariable(strAux)) Then
                        colAux.Add strAux, UCase$(strAux)
                    End If
                Else
                    forceExitLoop = True
                End If
            Loop
        End With
    Next
    
    Set GetVariablesFirstLevel = colAux
    Set colAux = Nothing
    Set objStoryRange = Nothing
Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: Do some research on using Find with wildcards. There have been several examples on SO recently.

Answer (score 0):

This might put you on the right track.

```
Public Sub checkHeadings()
Dim d As Word.Document
Dim p As Paragraph
Dim s As String
    Set d = ActiveDocument
    For Each p In d.Paragraphs
        If Not p.Range.Style Is Nothing Then
            If Left(p.Range.Style, Len("Heading")) = "Heading" Then
                s = fcGetText(p.Range.Text)
                If s <> "" Then
                    Debug.Print s
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    d.Close
End Sub

Function fcGetText(s As String) As String
Dim arr() As String
    arr = Split(s, "-")
    If UBound(arr) = 2 Then
        fcGetText = s
    Else
        fcGetText = ""
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the code ...But how to find the "s" value in the entire word document.

Comment: Sorry for not reading the question thoroughly. I have edited my answer completely.

Answer (score 0):

If you select' Use wildcards' in the Find/Replace dialog (under 'Find->Advanced Find->more>>'), then you can use an asterisk `*` to mean any set of any characters.

So this search:

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "-  test* -"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindAsk
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
```

finds all your candidates.

- [UHAS Computer Training](https://uhasct.com/use-wildcards-to-find-and-replace-in-word/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20Microsoft%20Word%20to%20find%20and,finds%20%E2%80%9C%20ban%20%E2%80%9D%20and%20%E2%80%9C%20balloon%20%E2%80%9C%29.)

has a list of wildcards you can also use to search with.